# What does "先が気になる" mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

Found in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/yu_ukina/status/1096622597624623104):

> 先が気になる

I always have to do a double check with 先 because the possible meanings can be very opposite one another.

I've also found other tweets with the same hashtag, like [this](https://twitter.com/tett333/status/1124839916343480320).

> 先が気になって仕方ない

Answer (score 19, accepted):

「先{さき}」 here means "**the future**", "**the future events/developments**", etc.

「先が気になる」 therefore means "**(I am) curious about the future developments**".

**Pitch accent is king:**

「さき{HL}」 (high-low) refers to a **past** event.  「先の国会{こっかい}」 ("the last national assembly")

「さき{LH}」 (low-high) refers to a **future** event all by itself.　「先が気になる」

Native speakers would never say 「先が気になる」 to refer to a past event.

We ***do say***, however, 「**さっき**のことが気になる。」 with the small っ to refer to a past event.  "**I am worried/curious about what happened a while ago**."  Again, that is "high-low".

Comment: Interestingly, no monolingual dictionary seems to mention the HL pitch for that definition of 先. 新明解, 大辞泉, and NHKアクセント辞典 tend to be pretty good at mentioning when a given definition has a different pitch from the rest so I’m a little surprised that none of them mention the different pitch. BTW it reminds me a little of the HL 右 one hears in legal contexts to mean “above” or “aforementioned” etc. (Also welcome back)

Comment: Oh shoot, I just missed it, 大辞林 has a note at the very end of their entry!  “〔アクセント⑤⑪は[0] [1]〕”

Answer (score 2):

Since the topic is TV series, in this case it refers to the future [episodes].

E.g. 
“(Very) curious about what happens next”

“Can’t help thinking about the next episode”